# have to search a query on a database such as a name and spit out anything that is similar

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, odbc

Basically it reads the database file on site, I want to then search a name for instance and then it will pop up with all results which are like the searchName and then output that as a table on a web page, this should be triggered by pressing the button and having typed a letter at least I have been fiddling with this for hours can anyone give me some insight on what I'm doing wrong? I'm also using Odbc to create a DNS on my system, this is a small project just need some trouble finding help as the Odbc code works for adding a record and viewing all records but messes up on this page.

Cheers, Josh

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>

<%
    OdbcConnection oConn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=sailors");
    oConn.Open();

    string str_sql = "select * from MonsterList where MonsterNames like searchName"; // this is an sql string   '*' includes all fields from table

    OdbcCommand oCmd = new OdbcCommand(str_sql, oConn);

    OdbcDataReader oRs = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Search Monster</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form method="post" runat="server">

    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Search </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="searchName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Search" />
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>

 </form>
    <table <link rel="displayrecordSS" href="displayrecordSS.css"/> 
        <%
            while(oRs.Read())
            {
                string str_out = @"<tr valign=""top"">" +
                                  "<td>" + oRs["MonsterNames"] + "</td>" +
                                  "<td>" + oRs["Element"] + "</td>" +
                                  "<td>" + oRs["Weakness"] + "</td>" +
                                  "</tr>" +
                                  @"<tr bgcolor=""#ff0000""><td height=""1"" colspan=""3""></td></tr>";

                Response.Write(str_out);

            }

        %>


</body>
</html>

<%
    oRs.Close();
    oRs = null;

    oCmd.Dispose();
    oCmd = null;

    oConn.Close();
    oConn.Dispose();
    oConn = null;
%>
```

Working Add Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>

<%
    OdbcConnection oConn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=sailors");
    oConn.Open();

    if ((Request["MonsterNames"] != null) && (Request["Element"].ToString() != ""))
    {

        string str_sql = @"insert into MonsterList (MonsterNames,Element, Weakness) values " +
        "('" + Request["MonsterNames"] + "'," +
        "'" + Request["Element"] + "', '" + Request["Weakness"] + "')";

        OdbcCommand oCmd = new OdbcCommand(str_sql, oConn);
        oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        oCmd.Dispose();
        oCmd = null;

        Response.Write("<br><br><br>");
    }


%>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Add Monster</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
            <a href="MainPg.aspx" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="Display Record.aspx">Monster List</a>
            <a href="Search Record.aspx">Search A Monster</a>
        </div>

                                                    <!-- all FORM elements (input, checkbox etc) contains data to submit. start of FORM -->
    <form method="post" runat="server">

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Monster Name:</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="MonsterNames" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>It's Element:</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Element" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Known Weaknesses (Seperate by '/'):</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Weakness" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Add Record" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>


</body>
</html>

<%

    oConn.Close();
    oConn.Dispose();
    oConn = null;
%>
```

Working Display All Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.Odbc" %>

<%
    OdbcConnection oConn = new OdbcConnection("DSN=sailors");
    oConn.Open();

     string str_sql = "select * from MonsterList "; // this is an sql string   '*' includes all fields from table

      OdbcCommand oCmd = new OdbcCommand(str_sql, oConn);

    OdbcDataReader oRs = oCmd.ExecuteReader();

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Monster List</title>
</head>

<body leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0" topmargin="0">
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
            <a href="MainPg.aspx" class="active">Home</a>
            <a href="Add Monster.aspx">Add Monster</a>
            <a href="Search Record.aspx">Search A Monster</a>
        </div>

    <table <link rel="displayrecordSS" href="displayrecordSS.css"/> 
        <%
            while(oRs.Read())
            {
                string str_out = @"<tr valign=""top"">" +
                                  "<td>" + oRs["MonsterNames"] + "</td>" +
                                  "<td>" + oRs["Element"] + "</td>" +
                                  "<td>" + oRs["Weakness"] + "</td>" +
                                  "</tr>" +
                                  @"<tr bgcolor=""#ff0000""><td height=""1"" colspan=""3""></td></tr>";

                Response.Write(str_out);

            }

        %>



    </table>
</body>
</html>


<%
    oRs.Close();
    oRs = null;

    oCmd.Dispose();
    oCmd = null;

    oConn.Close();
    oConn.Dispose();
    oConn = null;
%>
```

Comment: This line `<table <link rel="displayrecordSS" href="displayrecordSS.css"/>` seems error prone. can you share your generated HTML as well?

Comment: @msd The link to the style sheet was me messing around with the way the data was displayed however it didnt work out, I keep getting an error on the odbcdatareader oRs line saying it's expecting something but for the life of me can't figure out what.